# No route matches [PATCH] "/editer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My error is: No route matches [PATCH] "/editer"

Routes:

```
get "/editer", :to => 'users#edit'
post "/editer", :to => 'users#update'
```

Controller:

```
def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            redirect_to :action=>"show", :id=>@user.id
            flash[:success] = "ok"
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
end
```

View:

```
<%=s imple_form_for @user ,:html=>{class: "form-horizontal", id: "form" } ,:url => editer_url do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email (*)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%=f .input :email, :label=>false, :id=>"email", :placeholder => 'Email', :class=>"form-control required email", :name=>"email", :type=>"text" %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches [PATCH] "/editer"

You need to change

```
post "/editer", :to => 'users#update'
```

to

```
patch "/editer", :to => 'users#update'
```

Comment: Now I have the following error: `Could not find User with 'id' =`

Comment: @SmithZahir Can you post the params that are generated?

Comment: **Insert **`<% = hidden_field_tag: id, @ user.id%>` because I was not getting the id in update and now I get a rolback not updated: `Parameters: {"utf8" => "✓""authenticity_token"=>"Up+onyR3BLbOZO6dfb+hSIS9sFqgUrTDeldJGUfmOwGgdAmPEq9bvxwv/YI8nKy+7oQdQxtbP0lgSxHqeMmuiQ==", "user" => {"email" => "correo1@example.com"}, "id" => "1"}
   User Load (0.2ms) SELECT `users`. * FROM` users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    (0.1ms) BEGIN
   User Exists (0.1ms) SELECT 1 FROM `users` AS one WHERE (` users`.`email` = 'correo1@example.com' AND `users`.`id`! = 1) LIMIT 1
    (0.1ms) ROLLBACK`

Comment: @SmithZahir Do you a user record with id = 1 in users table?

Comment: If I have a user registered with id = 1

Comment: Yes, If I have a user registered with id = 1

Answer (score 0):

The protocol of RESTful API states that `PATCH` verb is more apt for *updating* and `POST` verb is for *creating*.

Rails follows this convention and hence the error, since you've declared the route with `post` verb. Just change that line from `post "/editer", :to => 'users#update'`
to

```
patch "/editer", :to => 'users#update'
```

You might as well consider making `user` resource, which will make things more semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of incorrect use of `HTTP verbs` (your routes should be defined as `patch ...`), you're getting an error because you're not conforming to the [*resourceful*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) routing structure of Rails:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "editer", only: [:edit, :update], path_names: { edit: "", update: "" } #-> url.com/editer/:id

<%= simple_form_for @user ,:html=> {class: "form-horizontal", id: "form" } do |f| %>
```

This wouldn't matter (you can do anything you want in Rails); the difference is that you're using the standardized `resourceful` action setup in your controller (which requires `params[:id]`).

The above should fix the issue for you.

Comment: On the form I'm not using editer: `resources :users, path: "editer", only: [:edit, :update], path_names: { edit: "", update: "" } #-> url.com/editer/:id`, as should be my settings in the route file? Even I can not edit the record.

Comment: Your routes were `get "/editer" => "users#edit"` etc, which my routes fixed

Comment: On the form I'm not using editer: `resources :users, path: "editer", only: [:edit, :update], path_names: { edit: "", update: "" } #-> url.com/editer/:id`, as should be my settings in the route file? Even I can not edit the record my error is `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1"`.

Comment: Your form clearly states `url: editer_url`, so *yes*, you are using `editer` in your form

Comment: In my console, I get that already exists and does not update rollback:
`User Exists (0.1ms) SELECT 1 FROM `users` AS one WHERE (` users`.`email` = 'correo1@example.com' AND `users`.`id`! = 1) LIMIT 1
    (0.2ms) ROLLBACK`

Comment: Okay, this is a step forward. Does your form submit okay? Can you post the submitted params from your console?

Comment: Parameters: `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nsuuxNW4ZQI4VH2Sn9yxFY8VcQwUoHv1c6IoxP1yWiw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"correo1@example.com"}, "a"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}`

Comment: Thanks bud! Can I ask what `a` is in this? Where does it come from?

Comment: the my form: `<div><label> <%= f.radio_button :signed_on,@user.signed_on, :type=>'radio', :value=>'option1', :name=>'a' %> Si </label></div>
                            <div><label> <%= f.radio_button :signed_on,@user.signed_on, :type=>'radio', :value=>'option2', :name=>'a' %> No </label></div>`

Comment: Thanks bud, let me take a look